# Compare colored strings PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am parsing a `shell_exec` for which I get a series of result strings, which I am comparing against data from other sources.

The input shell text contains ANSI colored text, which I can't seem to parse out.  As a result, I can't do a basic string comparison, let alone an `in_array` as I'd planned.

I have attempted to use `preg_replace` with a number of PCRE classes (print, cntrl, etc) as well as simpler things like `strcmp` and `strtolower`, all to no avail.

I'm sure I'm missing something stupid, but I haven't been able to figure out which stupid thing I'm missing.

Comment: can you show us the strings?

Comment: I'm not sure what that would do, since copying/pasting them would just do it via plaintext.  But, for edification, here is an echo of left vs. right:  /var/www/eastwood-dev/r2/socket/server.js::/var/www/eastwood-dev/r2/socket/server.js

Comment: Quick thought, pipe the ouput through `cat -vet`, which will tame the escape codes.

Comment: not sure how i can process a string i cant see.

Comment: Run the command producing the colored output, and pipe it to `cat -vet`: `mycommand | cat -vet`. Then paste whatever it displays. As an example, run this: `T_RED="${T_RED-$(tty -s && tput setaf 1)}" T_NORMAL="${T_NORMAL-$(tty -s && tput sgr0)}" echo "${T_RED}This is red.${T_NORMAL}" | cat -vet`. You should see `^[[31mThis is red.^[(B^[[m$`.

Comment: @Dagon - they're non-printing characters. What is it you expect to see? :  )

Comment: if i cant reproduce the error how could i fix it?

Comment: `cat -vet` will display them. We need an example to work with. Also, can we see how you "attempted to use preg_replace with a number of PCRE classes (print, cntrl, etc) as well as simpler things like strcmp and strtolower"? You've been here for a while, you know we're going to ask you to demonstrate code.

Comment: @Dagon - It i sa conceptual error.  The question is looking for somebody to provide a means of stripping non-printing characters.  Beating on it with a hammer doesn't always work.

Comment: im sure the help section says something about that :)

Comment: @Amadan - So, here's the cat.  Sorry, it took me a minute because I needed to reverse back more than a few steps.
^[[90m/var/www/eastwood-dev/r2/socket/server.js^[[39m

Comment: replace between ^ and m ?

Comment: @Dagon: `^[` is one character (escape, `\e`).

Comment: @Amadan: if the preg_replace runs on the result of cat -vet, then ^[ is two characters.  And, personally, I'd use the preg_replace on cat -vet output anyway.

Comment: i bow to your authority on the matter

Comment: @bishop: I thought we were using `cat -vet` as diagnostics, not as serious step in resolving the issue.

Comment: @Amadan Yep, and if using \e.* PCRE gets the job done great. There are just a lot unknowns in this qustion, and cat -vet will weed out any other oddities that might be easier to deal with than escape codes.

Comment: @bishop: I don't like that approach since it could also catch valid two-character sequences of `^[`.

Comment: @Amadan Yep, sage advice. Lots of unknowns here, *caveat emptor*, YMMV, etc.!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To weed out ANSI sequences:

```
preg_replace("/\e.*?[a-zA-Z]/", '', $str);
```

I believe you will always have the pattern of "escape, arguments, command" where the command is alphabetic, arguments numeric separated by colons if more than one.

Comment: That's not doing it.  I'm getting this:  `^[[90m/var/www/eastwood-dev/r2/socket/server.js^[[39m::/var/www/eastwood-dev/r2/socket/server.js$`, which is created from this line:  `echo trimEx($key).'::'.$serverpath."\n";`  And trimEx is `function trimEx($string)
{
    return preg_replace("/\e.*?;/", '', $string);;
}`

Comment: Sorry, I updated the question a couple of seconds after posting, since I realised I remembered ANSI sequences wrong. Try the updated regexp.

Comment: Awesome, this update makes more sense... but better yet, it totally works.  No idea why nothing else I tried would strip it out, but I'm glad we found (or rather, you handed me) a solution.

Comment: "No idea why nothing else I tried would strip it out" - this is why we ask for code samples :)

Answer (score 1):

Just throwing this out there. `cat -vet` is great for diagnostics, but sometimes it's great for dealing with non-porcelain output in a straight-forward way.

Give this a whirl:

```
$output = shell_exec("$cmd | cat -vet");
$output = preg_replace('/\^\[\[\d+m/', '', $output);
```

`cat -vet` is converting escape codes to individual printable characters, which you can then deal with as the actual characters themselves.

If your output has legitimate `^]` and other similar sequences, this approach won't work.  It's best to use PCRE that matches the actual escape codes as in @Amadan answer.  But if you need something quick and dirty, this may work.